# Show that $\gcd(a,b)=\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$ if and only if $a=b$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

I know how to prove $a=b$ only if $\gcd(a,b)=\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$, but I don't know how to prove the "if part". Can anyone help me?

Comment: What are you allowed to assume? For example, if you are allowed to use the fact that every number has a unique prime factorization, then the proof is almost trivial (if it still isn't, I can write it as an answer)

Comment: Have you attempted it by assuming that $\gcd(a,b)\ne lcm(a,b)$?

Comment: Note that we need to assume in addition that $a$ and $b$ are positive.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** $\gcd(a,b)\le a,b$ and ${\rm lcm} (a,b)\ge a,b$.

Answer (score 8):

Let $a<b$

Then:
$$\gcd(a,b)≤a$$
$$\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)≥b$$

Let $$\gcd(a,b)=\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)=x$$
since $$\gcd(a,b)≤a≤b≤\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$$
so $$x≤a≤b≤x$$
so $a=b=x$

Comment: Since we assumed $a<b$, then how can we write $a \leq b$ in the $\gcd(a,b) \leq a \leq b \leq lcm(a,b)$ ?

Answer (score 3):

*Hint*: If $(a,g)\in \mathbb{N}^{*}\times \mathbb{N}^{*}$, $a$ divides $g$ and $g$ divides $a$, then $a=g$.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic), for any $a,b$ we can write $$a=\prod_n p_n^{\alpha_n} ,b=\prod_n p_n^{\beta_n},$$ where $\{p_n \}$ is the increasing sequence of primes.
Now, $$gcd(a,b)=lcm(a,b) \Leftrightarrow \prod_n p_n^{\min(\alpha_n,\beta_n)}=\prod_n p_n^{\max(\alpha_n,\beta_n)} \Leftrightarrow \forall n \; \alpha_n=\beta_n \Leftrightarrow a=b.$$

Answer (score 0):

A brain-dead approach to this problem would be to analyze the problem one prime at a time. Any positive integer can be uniquely represented by the number of times each prime divides that integer (i.e. its "prime factorization"). The $\text{lcm}$ and $\gcd$ are easy to express in this form....

Comment: I'm sure this will work, but sometimes these results about gcd and lcm are used as lemmas to prove the fundamental theorem of arithmetic