# In the following answer, since we assumed $a<b$, then how can we write $a \leq b$ in $\gcd(a,b)\leq a\leq b\leq\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$ statement?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[This is the answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/502587/455531)

Kindly help me figure out.

Comment: Just change the first line to $a \leq b$.

Comment: Since $2 < 5$ then how can we say $2 \le 5$.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because very low quality

Comment: @Buraian Even thought it's low quality, it helped me clear a concept I didn't know before, no matter how trivial this was, I actually didn't know this before. I feel really sad you downvoted my question, I'm a struggling newbie in Math, earning reputation is very hard for me. And I had to struggle really hard for Math, it's not like I met many Mathematicians in real life, maybe zero.

Comment: @Buraian I actually asked for clarification beneath the answer, but I found out the author wasn't an active user anymore. So I posted the question.

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't know. I think the question could have been formatted better. However now I think again I suppose someone who had this doubt in the linekd question could find help

Comment: @Buraian it's alright. How should this be formatted better, what is necessary to edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\le$ means $<$ *OR* $=$.   If $M < N$ then it *is* true that $M<N$ *OR* $M = N$ so it *is* true that $M \le N$.

For example  $2 < 5$ so $2 \le 5$.

That's not a problem.  $2 < 5$ is a *STRONGER* statement that $2\le 5$ but a *STRONGER* statement being true doesn't mean the weaker statement *isn't* true.  In fact if the stronger statement *is* true than the weaker statement must be true as well.

Take "Wonder Woman is an Amazonian Princess" vs.  "Wonder Woman is a person".  The first statement is true.  But that doesn't make the second statement false.  In fact if the first statement is true the second statement *must* be true because you can't be an Amazon Princess *without* being a person!

And in the same way if we *every*  have $M < N$ then we must also have $M \le N$.  We can't have $M < N$ but $M$ *NOT* being less than or equal to $N$.

Answer (score 1):

$a<b$ means that $a \le b$.

This is kind of intuitive, but if you want a sort of more formal proof, here (it's still pretty intuitive anyways).

Rearrange $a<b$ gets $0<b-a$, so $b-a$ is positive. Rearranging $a\le b$ gets us $0\le b-a$. But we know that $b-a$ is positive, so then $0\le b-a$ is true.

For example, as @fleablood stated in the comments, $2<5$ and $2\le 5$ are both true.

Comment: No it doesn't ‘mean’.

Comment: @Bernard Edited.